# Grafana, postgresql: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, grafana, window-functions

In Grafana, we want to show bars indicating maximum of 15-minut averages in the choosen time interval. Our data has regular 1-minute intervals. The database is Postgresql.

To show the 15-minute averages, we use the following query:

```
SELECT
  timestamp AS time,
  AVG(rawvalue) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 7 FOLLOWING) AS value,
  '15-min Average' AS metric
FROM database.schema
WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp) AND device = '$Device'
ORDER BY time
```

To show bars indicating maximum of raw values in the choosen time interval, we use the following query:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(timestamp,'$INTERVAL') AS time,
  MAX(rawvalue) AS value,
  'Interval Max' AS metric
FROM database.schema
WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp) AND device = '$Device'
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(timestamp,'$INTERVAL')
ORDER BY time
```

A naive combination of both solutions does not work:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(timestamp,'$INTERVAL') AS time,
  MAX(AVG(rawvalue) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 7 FOLLOWING)) AS value,
  'Interval Max 15-min Average' AS metric
FROM database.schema
WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp) AND device = '$Device'
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(timestamp,'$INTERVAL')
ORDER BY time
```

We get error: "pq: aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls".

There is a suggestion on SO to use "with" ([Count by criteria over partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836772/count-by-criteria-over-partition)) but I do not know hot to use it in our case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the first query as a CTE (or `with`) for the second one. The `order by` clause of the CTE and the `where` clause of the second query as well as the `metric` column of the CTE are no longer needed. Alternatively you can use the first query as a derived table in the `from` clause of the second one.

```sql
with t as
(
 SELECT
   timestamp AS time,
   AVG(rawvalue) OVER(ORDER BY timestamp ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 7 FOLLOWING) AS value
 FROM database.schema
 WHERE $__timeFilter(timestamp) AND device = '$Device'
)
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(time,'$INTERVAL') AS time,
  MAX(value) AS value,
  'Interval Max 15-min Average' AS metric
FROM t
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

Unrelated but what are `$__timeFilter` and `$__timeGroup`? Their sematics are clear but where do they come from? BTW you may find [this](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/Interval-date_trunc) function useful.

Comment: $__timeFilter and $__timeGroup are Grafana macros, see https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/

Comment: I see. So Grafana pre-processes the query text upfront, right?